# what is the reaction between copper and an acid

Tags: acid-base

what happens when copper is reacted with hydrochloric acid may be dilute or concentrated.Should it displace hydrogen?if not what will happen if yes why?i think it will not react because copper is placed below hydrogen

Comment: Well, you are pretty much correct, but if you are interested you may want to read about $E^\circ$ values to find out why copper is "below hydrogen".

Comment: you can react it if you use hydrogen peroxide. I believe you can etch copper on PCBs this way